# Paths settings for unittest

Tags: python-unittest

I have an application with several microservices located in different folders + tests folder:

```
project/
  main_app/
    ...
  microservice1/
    ...
  microservice2/
    ...
  common_utils/
    crawler.py
  tests/
    orders/
      test_orders.py
```

The application works fine but Unittest gives me a hard time. If I run one test explicitly like `python3 -m unittest tests.orders.test_orders` it works fine too. But if I run `python3 -m unittest discover tests` I get an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common_utils.crawler'

I understand it's somehow related to paths defined so unittest doesn't add `projects` folder to module search paths. How do I add it?

Update: if I run `python3 -m unittest` or `python3 -m unittest discover` it works fine too as described [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue24247#msg248940). But the problem is that I use VSCode for testing and it seems it uses `python3 -m unittest discover tests` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for VSCode I found a solution. I've just commented out following lines in `config.json`:

```
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        // "-s",
        // "./tests",
        // "-p",
        // "test_*.py"
    ],
```